# What is the best way to store tooltip titles to be edited in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, tooltip

I'm currently building a form in **ASP.NET MVC 4**.
I know how to make the tooltips and they work just fine, BUT...

The application has an admin panel, where I want to be able to **change the title for each tooltip**, so the customer can change these values themself.
I have 14 properties in a viewmodel which each needs a tooltip.

What would be the best possible way to store these titles?

I'm using EF6 and guess they should be **stored in the DB**, but with relations to underlying properties or not?
And if YES then how?

I tried to hardcode the titles in the viewmodel and present it like `@Model.PropertyTooltip`, but MVC only renders properties **{** get; set; **}** and not fields (`prop = "tooltiptext";`) as far as I know.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

**EDIT:**
Example of binding

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="@Model.NameTooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
```

Still new to asking questions here, so post feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your view ,to check how you are binding the tooltip

Comment: Just made an edit. Thanks

Comment: i hope you are doing it right..even ill do like this

Comment: @Suprajv you can store them within a session or if you want to handle it in client side you can store it within a variable of javascript or its libs

Comment: you can store in a javascript variable, but why do u want to store a tooltip??

Comment: @Suprajv As i clearly write in my question; it should the possible for the customer of the application to change the tooltips in an admin panel.

Comment: then in admin panel create a form with textbox and provide an option to edit the tooltip

Comment: I know that. But you cannot edit serverside data unless it was saved somewhere in the first place? And I want to know where and how it should be saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind on reading your question is that it looks like a problem that can be better solved by using Resource files (.resx).

Create a table that stores these key values. Whenever a user updates a value, you would need to regenerate the resource package on the fly.

In your view code, you just mention the key in your anchor tags the corresponding value can be pulled from the resx file.

If you are willing to go down that route then I can try to expand on this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't thought about that. I will try it out, and mark as answer if I do not need more knowledge.

Comment: Hi again. Just wanted to update to let others know. I ended up using a .resx file which holds the different titles in a table. Then I call the values from the view.